# Call a key from a dictionary without knowing its name

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, key

Is there a way to call a key without directly calling it? For example, if I have this code and I want to call "Voltage_active(V)" without typing "Values['Voltage_active']" is there a way to do that?

```
    Values = {"Voltage_active(V)" : 10, }
```

I wanted to create a new variable like below, but that code does not work

```
    functional_voltage = Values[key]
```

Comment: Do you want `Values.values()[0]`?

Comment: Yes thank you that worked

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You show a dictionary that has only one entry.    In that case, observe that we can obtain its value via:

```
>>> Values = {"Voltage_active(V)" : 10, }
>>> list(Values.values())[0]
10
```

By using `list`, we have made this compatible with Python3 as well as Python2.